# AWS lambda cannot access DynamoDB after being placed in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

As the title suggests, I placed my Lambda function in a private subnet and now It cannot access or timeout when scanning the DB. Prior to this, it could access and scan the DB. What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include details about why you wish to connect the Lambda function to a VPC. For example, does it need to access resources inside the VPC, in addition to DynamoDB? Also, you mention IoT in your comments, so could you please provide information about what you wish to do with IoT. (Please edit your question to add these details, rather than answering via a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Your DynamoDB resources are not in your VPC. Since you've configured your Lambda functions to connect to your VPC, you need to setup a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance to allow your private resources to access the internet. As the docs state:

> AWS Lambda uses the VPC information you provide to set up ENIs that
>   allow your Lambda function to access VPC resources. Each ENI is
>   assigned a private IP address from the IP address range within the
>   Subnets you specify, but is not assigned any public IP addresses.
>   Therefore, if your Lambda function requires Internet access (for
>   example, to access AWS services that don't have VPC endpoints), you
>   can configure a NAT instance inside your VPC or you can use the Amazon
>   VPC NAT gateway. You cannot use an Internet gateway attached to your
>   VPC, since that requires the ENI to have public IP addresses.

[AWS Lambda Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html)

Comment: Do you happen to know about AWS IOT? I want to connect my lambda (in VPC) to AWS IOT using VPC endpoint. But AWS IOT is not listed in the supported services. Does this mean that I need to use NAT gateway? (I am avoiding NAT gateway since it's expensive and are not provided in the free tier serivces)

Comment: VPC Endpoints support 50+ services, not just S3 and DynamoDB (which are a specific type of VPC Endpoint called a gateway endpoint). It doesn't support IOT, however.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the following:

- The route table for the Lambda has a NAT Gateway for internet traffic that resides in public subnet.
- DynamoDB Gateway endpoint exists? Check its policy to ensure that it is not limited to specific sources
- Outbound access is allowed via the security group and NACL

Comment: Do you happen to know about AWS IOT? I want to connect my lambda (in VPC) to AWS IOT using VPC endpoint. But AWS IOT is not listed in the supported services. Does this mean that I need to use NAT gateway? (I am avoiding NAT gateway since it's expensive and are not provided in the free tier serivces)

Comment: Hi yes you’ll need to use NAT, if you’re trying to cut costs try looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html. It won’t be as resilient but will be cheaper :)